# Resources image assets could not load when Cocoapod lib developing (Only occur on real iPhone. Simulator is work well)

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

I create a project use `pod lib create`.

[image: project structure]

That `CKTextView/Resources/CKTextView/Assets/image.xcassets` contain two image about checkBox style.

[image]

And I init a UIButton in CheckBoxListItem.swift file.

```swift
private func setupCheckBoxButton(keyY: CGFloat, ckTextView: CKTextView)
{
    let lineHeight = ckTextView.font!.lineHeight
    let distance = lineHeight - 4

    button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 12, y: keyY + 3, width: distance, height: distance))
    button!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.checkBoxButtonAction(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    changeCheckBoxButtonBg()

    // Append label to textView.
    ckTextView.addSubview(button!)
}

func changeCheckBoxButtonBg() {
    let name = isChecked ? "icon-checkbox-checked" : "icon-checkbox-normal"

    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: CheckBoxListItem.self)
    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: name, inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)

    button!.setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, forState: .Normal)
}
```

Test on the iPhone Simulator, it's work very well. But when I run on the real iPhone 5S, the backgroundImage always nil.

[image]

I can't find the reason when I debug 4 hours later, help me and thanks much.

*Project on Github: [CKTextView](https://github.com/chanricle/CKTextView)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code `let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: CheckBoxListItem.self)`

bundle value is: `/var/containers/Bundle/../CKTextView_Example.app/Frameworks/CKTextView.framework`

The 'CKTextView.bundle' in the CKTextView.framework.

Just forward find bundle can fix this bug.

Follow code:

```swift
let url = bundle.URLForResource("CKTextView", withExtension: "bundle", subdirectory: "", localization: "")  
let selfBundle = NSBundle(URL: url!)
let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: name, inBundle: selfBundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
```